# React Big Calendar is displaying my events 1 day earlier than the start and end dates I have set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-big-calendar

```
render() {
    const events = [];
    this.props.appointments.map(appointment => {
        events.push({
            start: appointment.start,
            end: appointment.end,
            title: appointment.title ? appointment.title : "booked",
            allDay: true
        })
    })
    return (
        <div className="calendar-container">
            <Calendar
                views={['month']}
                selectable="ignoreEvents"
                localizer={this.localizer}
                events={events}
                onSelectSlot={(slotInfo) => this.props.selectSlot(slotInfo)}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Both my seeded events and newly created events show up on the calendar, but they are highlighted on the calendar 1 day early. For example, here is one seed:

```
Appointment.create!({
listing_id: crystal_lake.id,
user_id: user.id,
start: "2019-11-05",
end: "2019-11-07",
num_guests: 2)}
```

I can create an event successfully with this but within the calendar, the dates 11-04 through 11-06 are highlighted

When I create an event in the component, I have it display the start and end days outside of the calendar and they are correct, but on the calendar, the same thing happens.

I'm not even sure what code to share because I think it's something to do with the library source code and I have no idea where to look. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I experienced a similar problem some time ago with a calendar component. Apparently all dates after july or so were moving one day ahead. Further investigation led to daylight savings being the issue. So you can set a date before June and see if you experience the same thing. Also a date like "2019-11-07" will be formatted by the component as "2019-11-07:23:59:59",  or "2019-11-07:00:00:00" and in the event of daylight saving, the first one will be rounded to the next day because of the additional 1 hour added

Comment: Going back to before June didn't change anything but I did add time to the date format of my events and that did the trick. Thanks for the advice!